# Compilation of firefox extension with xulrunner-sdk-36.0 C++

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

I have a FF toolbar working in all previous versions. My toolbar partially written in C++. I've tried to build the C++ part with a new xulrunner-sdk-36.0 
I've receive such link errors:

```
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsISupportsImpl.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsStringAPI.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsComponentManagerUtils.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsCOMPtr.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsCRTGlue.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
1>xpcomglue_s.lib(nsTArray.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1600' in Encryption.obj
```

From my first research I've understood that the problem in incompatibility of VS versions. I have tried to recompile VS2010 and VS2012 with same errors.

Somebody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_MSC_VER 1800` is Visual Studio 2013 and `1600` is Visual Studio 2010. Both compilers are not compatible to each other in C++ mode, so you'll need to recompile either your project or the SDK so that compilers match.

`1800` says to me that the xulrunner SDK was build using VS2013, [which is confirmed by the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites), while your project still uses VS2010. (I guess when you tried VS2012, it complained about `1700` not `1600`?)

So you either need to compile your project in VS2013, using the v120 Platform Toolset (See Project Properties/General), or compile a xulrunner SDK yourself using VS2010.

Starting with Gecko 37, you'll probably [need to use VS2013 anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites):

> Please note that as of Firefox 37, earlier versions of Visual Studio will not work. We've started using features of C++11 that are not supported in Visual Studio 2012 and earlier.